# Python: Increasing number of symbolic functions for each iteration of a loop

Tags: python, sympy

I am a beginner at programming in general, but I am somewhat familiar with ANSYS APDL language (a Fortran derivative) and Python.
In essence, I am trying create a new symbolic function for each iteration in a loop. As far as I've seen, Python (sympy, specifically) cannot create an array or list of symbolic functions. For example, in APDL, I may write:

```
*do,i,1,3
        f%i% = i*x + 2*i*y
*enddo
```

Which would give me 3 functions: `f1 = x + 2y, f2 = 2x + 6y, f3 = 3x + 9y`
So I'm wondering if there is a Python equivalent for the %i% functionality, or if there is a simple workaround in Python that I may be able to take advantage of.

My end goal is to bring all of these functions together to solve a system while still in the loop. Each iteration will increase the number of equations and variables in the system until certain criteria are met. I can increase the number of variables with `psi = sympy.Array(sympy.symbols('psi0:%d'%i))` , but I have yet to find a way to do it with symbolic functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With sympy you could do the following (note that in Python list are indexed starting from 0):

```py
from sympy import symbols

x, y = symbols('x y')
num = 3
f = [i*x + 2*i*y for i in range(1, num+1)]

print(f[0])
print(f[1])
print(f[2])
```

Output:

```
x + 2*y
2*x + 4*y
3*x + 6*y
```

To "call" such a sympy function, substitute its variables for values. Values can either be constants or expressions which may contain (other) variables.

```py
a = symbols('a')
print(f[0].subs({x: 7, y: 8}))
print(f[1].subs({x: a, y: a + 4}))
print(f[2].subs({x: 2*a, y: 3*a + 5}))
```

Output:

```
23
6*a + 16
24*a + 30
```

Answer (score 1):

If the name of the function doesn't matter to you, you can create lambda expressions and store them in a list:

```py
funcs = []
for i in range(8):
        new = lambda x,y : i*x + 2*i*y
        funcs.append(new)
```

you can then call them by

```py
>>> x, y = 2, 3
>>> funcs[0](x, y)
56
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just create a list of functions and call them by index.

```
functionList = []
for i in range(10):
    def func(x,y):
        return i * x + 2 *i *y
    functionList.append(func)

functionList[0](4,5)
functionList[1](1,5)
```